# Fullscreen borderless QDialog in Qt on Symbian

Tags: qt

Is there a way to show `QDialog` in Qt on Symbian without a border?

I show the dialog by this way:

```
QDialog dialog;
dialog.setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
dialog.exec();
```

But there's an awful border at the screen, that's what I want to hide.

I've tried to use `Qt::Splashscreen`, but then there's a qdialog with transparent background, that doesn't achieve my goal.

`Qt::FramelessWindowHint` doesn't change something also (borders shows again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [`setWindowOpacity`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop) after setting the `SplahScreen` flag in order to make it completely opaque.

```
dialog->setWindowOpacity(1.0);
```

Comment: thanks! i've tried this, but unfortunately, it changes nothing on Symbian :(